# Scala - Parse String until end of string

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

With scala-parser-combinators, I want to try parse with postfix string(`end`). but previous parser cought `end` contents. how to fix it?
(just changing `"[^z]".r` is not good answer.)

```
val input = "aaabbbzzz"
parseAll(body, input) // java.lang.IllegalStateException: `zzz' expected but end of source found

def body: Parser[List[String]] = content.+ <~ end
def content: Parser[String] = repChar // more complex like (repChar | foo | bar)
def repChar: Parser[String] = ".{3}".r // If change this like "[^z]{3}", but no flexibility.
def end: Parser[String] = "zzz"
```

I want to try like followings.

```
"""(.*)(?=zzz)""".r.into(str => ...check content.+ or not... <~ end)
```

1. search strings until `end` string.
2. then parse them with another parser.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812610/non-greedy-matching-in-scala-regexparsers

Comment: Using `noneGreedy`, the above case is enough thanks :)

I just notice the bottom pattern in my question is written easily...
`def pattern: Parser[String] = """(.*)(?=zzz)""".r ^^ { case text => parseAll(another, text) ...`

Comment: @krrrr38: Please answer your own question with the two solutions that you've encountered, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to use the `not` combinator. You just need to check that what you are parsing is not the `end` value.

The trick is that `not` doesn't consume the input, so if `not(end)` succeeds (meaning that `end` failed) then we didn't reach the stopping condition so we can parse the three characters with the `content` parser that made the `end` parser failing.

As with the non-greedy approach linked in comments, it will fail for an input that has characters after "zzz" in the input (such as `"aaabbbzzzzzz"` for example).

But it may be sufficient for your use case. So you could give it a try 
with:

```
def body: Parser[List[String]] = rep(not(end) ~> content) <~ end
```

In fact this is a kind of `takeUntil` parser, because it parses with `content` repeatedly until you're able to parse with `end`.